# datatables element in row triggers selected/deselect

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, datatables

I'm using the JQuery datatables plugin with the `select` extension and I need to use a `<select>` list in one of the fields (inside each row). The `<option>` gets the id from the selected row.

The problem is that each time I click the list element, the row `select` atrribute is triggered. This is ok if the user doesn't select any row and clicks the list, but if the row is already selected when the user clicks the list element, the row is deselected, causing the id to be empty.

I was thinking in disable the `<select>` list and enabling it only when the row is selected, preventing the `<select>` element from triggering the `select` attribute (this last part is where I get lost, it could be done with a dt option, jquery. I even tried, foolishly, some css option like z-index but then I realized it has nothing to do... ).

What I have in mind (so far...):

```
$('.select_class').on('click', function() {
    $(this).parent().parent().preventaddClass('.selected');
});
```

How would I do this?

The `<select>` list is part of the data that comes from the ajax source:

```
[{"id":76,/* other fields*/"the_select":"<select class=\"select_class\"><option value=\"add\">1234 \u20ac<\/option><option value=\"remove\" >Hide<\/option><\/select>"}]
```

Comment: restrict datatables from selecting on that column (https://datatables.net/reference/option/select.selector)

Comment: Yeah, that seems a better option than what I was thinking. Thanks!